# Nuxt-Mapbox MapboxDefaultPopup position dose not change with Mouseover event

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, mapbox, nuxtjs3, mapbox-gl

## My Problem

I have a `MapboxLayer` of some geo JSON data containing properties that I want to show on the `MapboxDefaultPopup` .  I have added an event listener called `Mouseover` on the layer. As the mouse moves from one polygon to another I want to show the properties on the popup of that polygon on which the mouse is hovering. 
It only shows the default popup with just one polygon and does not display for the other.

## My Code

Here is the  `MapboxLayer` that I have implemented

```js
<MapboxLayer
      :layer="{
        source: 'data',
        id: 'geojson-layer',
        type: 'line',
        paint: {
          'line-color': '#0052cc',
          'line-width': 2,
        },
      }"
      @mouseover="(e) => handleMouseMove(e)"
    />
```

The popup component has dynamic lat langs based on the mouse position

```js
<MapboxDefaultPopup
        popup-id="popup1"
        :lnglat="hoverInfo.lngLat"
        :offset="[0, -10]"
        :options="{
          closeOnClick: false,
        }"
      >
        <span class="test">Hello World! {{ hoverInfo.lngLat[0] }}</span>
      </MapboxDefaultPopup>
```

My handleMouseMove function just sets the **lat langs** for the popup

```js
const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
 // hoverInfo.value = null;
  hoverInfo.value = {
    lngLat: [e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat],
  };
};
```

## Desired Outcome

I want to show the popup dynamically for the polygon on which the mouse pointer is.